# JUnit @Rule to pass parameter to test

Tags: java, parameters, junit, junit-rule

I'd like to create [`@Rule`](http://blog.mycila.com/2009/11/writing-your-own-junit-extensions-using.html) to be able to do something like this

```
@Test public void testValidationDefault(int i) throws Throwable {..}
```

Where i is parameter passed to the test by [`@Rule`](http://blog.mycila.com/2009/11/writing-your-own-junit-extensions-using.html).

However I do get

```
java.lang.Exception: Method testValidationDefault should have no parameters
```

is there any way to bypass it and set the i parameter in the [`@Rule`](http://blog.mycila.com/2009/11/writing-your-own-junit-extensions-using.html)?

Comment: Is `@Rule` a JUnit provided annotation? Where is it supposed to be put?

Comment: FYI - I was using junit,hamcrest and junitparams jar files. I forgot to use this code `@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)` before my test class name. Then, I got the error you got - `java.lang.Exception: Method testMethod should have no parameters`.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

it can't be done, you can't pass parameters to test method even using @Rule.

Comment: See my response for a way to pass parameters, albeit without using `@Rule`.

Answer (score 12):

As IAdapter said you can't pass an argument using Rules, but you can do something similar.

Implement a Rule that holds all your parameter values and evaluates the test once for every parameter value and offers the values through a method, so the test can pull them from the rule.

Consider a Rule like this (pseudo code):

```
public class ParameterRule implements MethodRule{
    private int parameterIndex = 0;
    private List<String> parameters;
    public ParameterRule(List<String> someParameters){ 
        parameters = someParameters;
    }

    public String getParameter(){
        return parameters.get(parameterIndex);
    }

    public Statement apply(Statement st, ...){
        return new Statement{
             public void evaluate(){
                 for (int i = 0; i < parameters.size(); i++){
                     int parameterIndex = i;
                     st.evaluate()
                 }      
             }
        }
    }
}
```

You should be able to use this in a Test like this:

```
 public classs SomeTest{
     @Rule ParameterRule rule = new ParameterRule(ArrayList<String>("a","b","c"));

     public void someTest(){
         String s = rule.getParameter()

         // do some test based on s
     }
 }
```

Comment: I actually build a somewhat workable example from that: https://github.com/schauder/parameterizedTestsWithRules

Answer (score 8):

I use `@Parameters` and `@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)` for passing values to tests. An example can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/).

I did not know about the `@Rule` annotation, but after reading [this post](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/10/23/junit-4-7-rules/), I think it serves another purpose than passing parameters to the tests:

> If in your test class, you create a field pointing to an object implementing the MethodRule interface, and you mark this to be processed as a rule, by adding the @Rule implementation, then JUnit will call back on your instance for every test it will run, allowing you to add additional behavior around your test execution.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That last url you gave cannot be found.

Comment: @MarcoS The link for additional example of how to use Rule annotation is broken. Update your answer.

Comment: @OO7 thank your for your comment: I removed the link to the additional example, because the author had apparently deleted the page.

Answer (score 1):

recently i started [zohhak](http://zohhak.googlecode.com) project. it lets you write tests with parameters (but it's a runner, not a rule):

```
@TestWith({
   "25 USD, 7",
   "38 GBP, 2",
   "null,   0"
})
public void testMethod(Money money, int anotherParameter) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that it is no longer true that you can't pass parameters directly to a test method. It can now be done using [`Theories`](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/experimental/theories/Theories.html) and [`@DataPoints`](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/experimental/theories/DataPoints.html)/[`@DataPoint`](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/experimental/theories/DataPoint.html).

For example:

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class TestDataPoints {

    @DataPoints
    public static int [] data() {
        return new int [] {2, 3, 5, 7};
    }

    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    @Theory
    public void testTheory(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println(String.format("a=%d, b=%d", a, b));
        assertEquals(a+b, add(a, b));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a=2, b=2
a=2, b=3
a=2, b=5
a=2, b=7
a=3, b=2
a=3, b=3
a=3, b=5
a=3, b=7
a=5, b=2
a=5, b=3
a=5, b=5
a=5, b=7
a=7, b=2
a=7, b=3
a=7, b=5
a=7, b=7
```

With the test passing.

Comment: This doesn't allow to have several DataPoints, so this functionality is pretty useless in 99% of cases.

Comment: You can have multiple `@DataPoints`. If they are of different types then they get handled automatically, if they are of the same type you can use a [parameter supplier](http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2010/02/07/junit-theories/).  Slightly cumbersome to set up, but relatively straightforward to use once you do so.

Comment: Still much more complicated and cumbersome than DataProviders in TestNG. Though it looks to be pretty obvious that this feature is very helpful..